# which type of List implementation to use for holding in memory logs

Tags: java, list, concurrency

I am developing a custom appender for application which would write log message to a application level variable list. so, all threads running in applications would access this list to add message(write only operation) to this list concurrently.
There is separate job which would also be concurrently accessing this list and remove 25 items in bulk every few milliseconds. so, there is add and remove operations on list that would be performed concurrently.
Now, my question is that if I can use java.util.ArrayList? I saw somewhere that there can be problems in adding items to ArrayList concurrently. also, there would be definitely problem when we try to remove 25 items from list while other threads are adding to the list.

If I create my own implementation of List MYList which would simply create a new remove25() method and use synchronize qualifier for this method, would it solve my problem? or i shoudl go to more safe option like CopyOnWriteArrayList which may be quite bad in performance(??) because logging operations would need to be done by many application threads concurrently. please advise.

one update: since I dont need random access and need only sequential acess with lot of add and remove operations, a Linked list type of implementation would be better.

Comment: If you read the JavaDoc on `CopyOnWriteArrayList` you'll see that it will create a new copy of the internal array with each mutation (add, remove) and if that list gets big you could run into problems. Also most list implementations are not threadsafe so you'd a different implementation. Either use delegation to provide synchronization to the mutation methods, use a lock-free implementation (there probably are a few libraries that provide one) or - and that might be the best option for your requirements - use a threadsafe queue like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`

Comment: Offsite: maybe you find some interesting ideas here: http://www.se-radio.net/2015/02/episode-220-jon-gifford-on-logging-and-logging-infrastructure/

Comment: thanks Thomas and GhostCat. I will check these options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to protect your memory structure from concurrent modification. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` may be too expensive for your use case.

Alternativley you may want to consider the following:

- a thread safe blocking `app queue` that accepts `add` from applications
- a thread that `takes` (or perhaps `drains`) messages from `app queue` in batches and adds them to `logger queue`
- a thread safe blocking `logger queue`  that allows the logger to log the batches

The interaction would look like thisL

```
app --add--> app queue  <--take-- logger queue <--take-- logger
```

Alternatively you may use a ring buffer as log4j does ( https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html )

Comment: David, This seems to be a great idea. to have 2 queues. one for app threads to put messages and other one where each queue item is a batch of 25 messages which i exactly what I need. Now, I need a consumer for batch queue which holds collection of batches. I would take out one batch at a time. However, I need to ensure that my log messages are processed in exact sequence as much as possible. so, From batch queue,If I have competing consumers, I need to ensure that consumer taking out first batch finishes the processing before second one starts.

Comment: based on your description of the problem , I see no reason to have more than one thread reading from the batched queue (same goes for `app queue`)

Comment: I agree that one consumer thread for AppQueue can handle the job of creating batches of 25 messages and put it on LoggerQueue. However, There may be a need for more than one consumer when my application threads are producing more messages than one consumer may handle even if handling is in batch. Consumer operation on logger queue which involves writing messages via REST service will definitely be slower than producers(even if I am using batch of 25 messages).

Comment: Well, if you have a single thread consuming batches from the queue and it can't keep up with the producers your queue will grow which is not a problem if eventually the consumer is able to catch up. Having multiple consumers adds complexity  to the point I suggest using an existing solution such as log4j (see for a SOAP example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-log4j/index.html )

Comment: I accepted this solution as it closely matches to what I need. I need a list where many producers are adding to the list and one consumer is bunching them up and adding to another list. items from another list are processed by another consumer and this is also scalable as i just need to add more consumer workers to achieve higher throughput as this consumer is doing lot of i/o. I am using LinkedBlockingQueue because I would prefer LInkedList based implementation as I have only insert and remove operations. No random access is required.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a thread safe Queue like ArrayBlockingQueue which has a drainTo method which allows you to extract multiple values at once.

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100000);

// to add
queue.add(log);

// to grab up to 25 elements
queue.drainTo(copy, 25);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Removing in bulk is definitely plus in this solution and check it.

Comment: I would like to use LonkedBlockingQueue only for the reason that it has drainTo method which would allow me to take our 25 items at a time. Please tell me if drainTo(colection, maxsize=25) is atomic operation and it would be safe if more than 1 consumer is trying to call it on the same time when multiple concurrent producer threads are calling add.

Comment: @Mayur All the BlockingQueue implementations have drainTo https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo(java.util.Collection,%20int) and the ones under the concurrent package are thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

> The implementation of ArrayList is not synchronized. If multiple
>   threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of
>   the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized
>   externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or
>   deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array;
>   merely setting the value of an element is not a structural
>   modification.)
>
> This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some
>   object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists,
>   the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList
>   method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental
>   unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
> ```
>
> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods
>   are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after
>   the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own
>   remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

(from Java documentation)

CopyOnWriteArrayList is a thread-safe variant of ArrayList but it makes a fresh copy of the underlying array, thus overriding everything, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

What would you like to use is a `BlockingQueue` that is thread safe (and doesn't handle nulls); I suggest you to read more [about it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and the [Concurrent Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html)